# Specify hostname to jupyter notebook when running on remote server

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm running a notebook on a remote server, to which I connect from my local machine via browser. One slight annoyance I have is it prints this on start:

```
Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/xxxxxxx
0 active kernels
The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
http://(friendly or 127.0.0.1):8888/
```

Where `friendly` is the friendly name of the host. The FQDN of the host is actually `friendly.x.y.z.com`. I would like it to print this:

```
The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
http://friendly.x.y.z.com:8888/
```

so that the URL is directly clickable from the console. Is there a config option I can pass somewhere to do that in jupyter notebook to explicitly specify the hostname I want displayed?

To be clear, `http://friendly.x.y.z.com:8888/` resolves correctly in the browser despite the above message.

Answer (score 2):

You should first generate the config file:

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

Then using the config file you can set the custom URL by editing the config file ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py changing the following line:

```
c.NotebookApp.custom_display_url = 'http://friendly.x.y.z.com:8888'
```

So when you start the server it will show this URL concatenated with the token.